# Why is this circuit in RC network switched out?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

[image]

Hi, I'm taking a course of Electrical and Computer Engineering in my university.

I don't understand why the partial circuit on the right side of the switch is ignored after the switch is closed.

As you can see, the book says the network becomes (c) from (a) via the short circuit.

What happens to the short circuit and the circuit on the right side? I think the resistor and the voltage source can still affect the network but it seems not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply toplogical chirurgy: Add a second wire parallel to the switch. Adds a null loop to  the  voltage loop and current knot equations with the sum current divided and voltage diffences zero.

Then cut off the right circuit between the switch and the added wire.

The two currents are now divided for each circuit. The system of equations decomposes into two independent groups.